# Smooch to Line Message Giving Forbidden in Smooch Logs

Tags: smooch

I am trying to integrate with Line using Smooch. Everything is fine except I am not able to receive the message from Smooch to Line APP.
Giving Forbidden Error.

Below are the logs from Smooch Dashboard.

- Line to Smooch----OK
- Smooch to HTTP ---OK
- HTTP(API) to Smooch --OK
- **Smooch to Line -- Error: Forbidden**

403 Forbidden - Your credentials are valid but you don’t have access to the requested resource.

I am not sure which resource is not accessible. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The membership plan was not allowed for PUSH Messages.Now it is working after membership upgrade on LINE.

Comment: i had the same kind of issue, resolved with this step. thanks